# How to make JPG images that can be played as music files

Tags: mp3, jpeg, winamp

I came across a strange image:

[image]

Apparently, somehow they managed to make a JPG file also play as a media file. I'd like to know what program you use to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They may have used a dedicated steganography tool, but you can probably do it in a command-prompt.

1. Open a command-prompt (Win+R -> `cmd.exe` -> OK)
2. Type `copy /b`
3. Drag and drop a JPG to the command-prompt window
4. Type `+`
5. Drag and drop an MP3 to the command-prompt window
6. Type a filename (eg `Combined.jpg`), then press Enter

Open the new JPG in an image viewer, then in an audio player. It may or may not work depending on the viewer or player.